# How to trim all words in string above given length?

Tags: regex, r

For example this matches every word of length 3 or more, and replaces it with `xx`:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(c("This is a long", "Another one."), "([a-zA-Z]{3,})", "xx")
#output: "xx is a xx" "xx xx"
```

What I'd like to get is:

```
#"Thi is a lon" "Ano one."
```

Comment: A non regex solution could also be `sapply(strsplit(c("This is a long", "Another one."), ' '), function(x) paste(strtrim(x, 3), collapse = " "))`, but you''ll lose the punctuations.

Comment: Or a lookaround approach would be `gsub("(?<=[A-Za-z]{3})[A-Za-z]+", c("This is a long", "Another one."), perl=TRUE)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
([a-zA-Z]{3})[a-zA-Z]+
```

And replace with `\\1`

You can also use `gsub` (from comments)

```
gsub("([a-zA-Z]{3})[a-zA-Z]+", "\\1", c("This is a long", "Another one."))
```

Comment: Using R it would be `gsub("([a-zA-Z]{3})[a-zA-Z]+", "\\1", c("This is a long", "Another one."))`